# Store push notification when received in device in flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, push-notification

Can we store push notification in local database with title & description whenever it received in device in flutter app? I checked various articles but it doesn't clearly mentioned this. Specially on iOS. Users will receive push notifications whenever near by any truk available. So instead of storing push notifications on server or firebase for specific users, it would better to save them locally within the app. Any thoughts?

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!